# How can I fix my JS and jQuery to properly validate input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I am completely brand new to JS and jQuery. I have written a basic html form to calculate values and am wanting to validate each input and test to see if it contains a non-zero value but I can't figure it out. I have spent much time searching before posting this. Remember I am completely new so take it easy on me, please. Here is my script to test the inputs.

```
$('#ppm_Pt').on('change', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_num = input.val();
    if (is_num) 
    { 
        $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", false) 
    }
    else
    { 
        $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", true) 
    }
});
```

I can get this to work to check if there is any input for ppm_Pt, but instead I am wanting to check all inputs of type number in my html form and instead of just checking for any value I want to test against nulls and 0 values. I know there is a way. I have tried using the each() method but was unsuccessful. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: So these fields, they can be any number?  You just want to check for anything except a number?

Comment: Please provide some HTML

Comment: Yes all I have multiple input fields of type number and I would like to disable my calculate button when the user inputs a non-number, 0, or leaves it blank. In other words, when all number fields have been properly filled, then enable my calculate  button

Comment: @AdrianForsius  'code'                                                   '<div>                                                           <label for="ppm_Pt"> Ppm(Pt) </label>
 <input type="number" id="ppm_Pt" name="ppm_Pt" value="" />  </div>         
  <div>      <button id="Calculate" onclick="calc()" disabled> Calculate Price </button>
        </div> '

Comment: There are many other input fields similar to my ppm_Pt. I would like to be able to use jQuery to select all elements of type number and then validate. I realize in my original question I was only validating the single input of 'ppm_Pt'

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an ID selection on an element if this is your form you would probably do something like:

```
$('#ppm_Pt').on('change', 'input', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_num = input.val();
    if (is_num !== '') 
    { 
        $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", true); 
    }
    else
    { 
        $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", false); 
    }
});
```

Comment: if (is_num !== '') == if (is_num)

Comment: When I try this my button stays disabled no matter what I input in the field. Would I matter if my button is set to disabled in my html form already?

Comment: This code will test all my inputs and if any are changed my button is enabled. I would like to modify it to stay disabled until all number fields have been inputted.        `code:   $('input[type="number"]').on('change', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_num = input.val();
        if (is_num) {
            $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('#Calculate').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
`